# Connecting simple port of struct to a systemC instance

Tags: specman

I'm interested in writing a simple port of struct to a systemC class instance. Do I have to mark the e struct fields of intetest with physical fields(%)?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can use the new feature that converts e struct to c and vice versa.

When defining a port, use the

```
simple port of struct .. is instance
```